# xmlapi.php do cPanel não cria BD Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, whm

Tenho um servidor dedicado na Hostgator com acesso ao WHM. Ontem foi sugerida a atualização do próprio WHM e do cPanel para a nova versão 74.0.4

A partir disso não foi mais possível a criação de bancos de dados MySQL através do código PHP e do xmlapi.php

Alguém mais está passando por algum problema relacionado ao xmlapi ou à atualização do cPanel?

Link para xmlapi.php: https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php

Código para criação do BD:

```
$nome_bd = "usuario_cpanel" . md5(uniqid(time()));

$db_host = "minha_url";
$cpuser = "meu_usuario";
$cppass = "minha_senha";

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($db_host);
$xmlapi->set_port(2083);
$xmlapi->password_auth($cpuser, $cppass);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);

print($xmlapi->api1_query($cpuser, 'Mysql', 'adddb', array($nome_bd)));

$xmlapi->api1_query($cpuser, 'Mysql', 'adduserdb', array($nome_bd, 'usuario_bd', 'all'));
```

O log de erro é um pouco estranho, por isso acho que seja um problema no cPanel, e não no meu código, pois antes da atualização ele funcionava perfeitamente.

```
[09-Aug-2018 14:38:13 America/Sao_Paulo] RESPONSE:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1188352635" />
    <title>Login do cPanel</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAICAAAAEAIADSAgAAFgAAAIlQTkcNChoKAAAADUlIRFIAAAAgAAAAIAgGAAAAc3p69AAAAplJREFUWIXt1j2IHGUYB/DfOzdnjIKFkECIVWIKvUFsIkRExa9KJCLaWAgWJx4DilZWgpDDiI0wiViIoGATP1CCEDYHSeCwUBBkgiiKURQJFiLo4d0eOxYzC8nsO9m9XcXC+8MW+3z+9/l6l2383xH+iSBpElyTdoda26xsDqp/h0CVZ3vwKm7tMBngAs7h7eRYebG6hMtMBHbMBX89vfARHprQ5U8cwdFQlIOZCVR5di1+w/wWXT/EY6EoN5NZCODuKZLDwzgSMCuBe2fwfX6QZwtpWzqfBBtLC3txF/ZhxKbBGx0EfsTJS77vwmGjlZrD4mUzUOXZjVjGI65cnTXchB8iupdDUb7QinsQZ7GzZftdQj2JVZ49iC/w6JjksIo7OnS9tiA5Vn6GtyK2+1MY5NkhfGDygVrBAxH5WkPuMjR7/3UsUFLl2Q68s4XkA3ws3v9zoSjX28Kr5wL1xrTxa6ou+f6OZGvqPg9v1wZeaUjcELE/DVfNhWFSvy/enOIZ9eq1sTokEMNLWI79oirP8g6fXpVnh7GEvY1sV/OJ4f0UhyKKk6EoX4x5pEkgXv6L6OM99YqNw/c4kXSwG5nkIfpLCynuiahW1GWeJHkfT4aiXO9atz1XcD6I6yLyHu6bIPk6Hg9FeYZ63y9EjBarPDvQ8VJ1nd9V3D4m+RncForyxFCQ4hSeahlej88Hefauurdwaufr5z/F/ZHAX6nL+mZE18e36IWiHLkFocqzW9QXcNz1+wUHxJ/f10JRPjvGP4pk/vj5L3F8AtufdD+/p6dJDknzX+05fDLGtife/766t9MRgFCUffWTudwE3AqBlVCUf0xLYGTQqzzbhydwJ3Y34g318J1tmX+DPBTlz9MS2MY2/nP8DTGaqeTDf30rAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- EXTERNAL CSS -->
    <link href="/cPanel_magic_revision_1386192030/unprotected/cpanel/fonts/open_sans/open_sans.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/cPanel_magic_revision_1533726917/unprotected/cpanel/style_v2_optimized.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
/*
  This css is included in the base template in case the css cannot be loaded because of access restrictions
  If this css is updated, please update securitypolicy_header.html.tmpl as well
*/
.copyright {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  background-size: 25px auto;
}
    </style>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            behavior: url(/cPanel_magic_revision_1375211990/unprotected/cp_pngbehavior_login.htc);
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
    window.DOM = { get: function(id) { return document.getElementById(id) } };
    </script>
</head>
<body class="cp">




    <p class="logo"><img class="main-logo" src="/cPanel_magic_revision_1487348166/unprotected/cpanel/images/cpanel-logo.svg" alt="logo"></p>



<div class="error_notice">
    <div id="error-wrapper">
        <div id="error_msg_contents">
            <h2>Erro HTTP 404</h2>
    <p>A página solicitada não foi encontrada.</p>
    <h2>Possíveis motivos pelos quais você está vendo esta página:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Um URL indicado pode ter sido alterado desde a última vez que você o visitou.</li>
        <li>O URL foi inserido incorretamente.</li>
        <li>A URL foi digitada com uso impreciso de maiúsculas (as URLs <a href="http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity">diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas</a>).</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Verifique novamente o URL que está tentando acessar. (<a href="javascript:history.back()">Voltar</a>)</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="copyright">Copyright© 2018 cPanel, Inc.
    <br /><a href="https://go.cpanel.net/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></div>

</body>

</html>
[09-Aug-2018 14:38:14 America/Sao_Paulo] Some error message here
```

Fico grato se alguém puder ajudar ou pelo menos informar alguma situação semelhante que está passando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A XML API (xmlapi.php) do cPanel foi desativada e não funciona mais a partir da versão 74 do WHM / cPanel.

Veja a release note oficial: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/74+Release+Notes#id-74ReleaseNotes-RemovedXMLoutputinAPIfunctions